# Bash history pre-login

Tags: bash, command-history

I have a bash function that is frequently executed interactively but is executed by default during any user login. Part of this function needs to query bash history and does so using the `history` command. This works fine once the login process has completed but does not work before that.

Here is the relevant snippet, currently written into $HOME/.bashrc

```
data=$( history 2)
echo --------
echo $data
echo ---------
```

and the output when the function is executed as part of login

```
mike@:~$ ssh thehost
Last login: Mon May 18 19:46:52 2020 from 10.64.40.62

--------

--------
[18/05 19:47:24] ~ $ history 2
  128  18/05/20 19:47:08 vim .bashrc
  129  18/05/20 19:47:29 history 2
```

Can anyone help explain this?

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the user did not execute the commands in /etc/profile.d/* ?

Comment: No, I've checked that :) The function containing `history` is executed but nothing is returned.

Comment: Many thinks in the question are unclear. E.g. what do you mean by returned?

Comment: Sorry, its my first question, I'll edit it now.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to store the output of `history` in a variable before printing the value? You could just insert `history 2` in place of `echo $data`...

Comment: @Kusalananda, thats just to demonstrate the issue. Same happens either way.